# Why Mother used "child abuse" word in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Family having conversation at dining table. After seeing her elder sister getting served with coffee, so brother asks for him also.

> Young Son: I want coffee.
>
> Father: No way, dude. You don't give crack to somebody who's already
>   on speed.
>
> Mother: Don't worry, we switched him to decaf.
>
> Elder Daughter: As long as you don't switch me.
>
> Mother: No, baby, that would be **child abuse**.

Comment: Maybe because this is a poorly constructed joke?

Comment: It's exaggeration for humor, equating denying the daughter regular coffee with child abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is a joke.

"**Real**" coffee drinkers like the caffeine *kick* they get with their coffee and the Elder Daughter is making that obvious.

The Mother is equating giving *decaffinated* coffee to *abusively* denying something to a child.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "switch me" means "beat me with a small stick" or "spank me" or even perhaps "exchange me for something or someone else." The pun comes from the different meanings of switch; the phrase "switch me" is short for "switch me to another type of coffee" or short for "switch my coffee."

Comment: Interesting that there are two completely different ways to take the given quote with humorous intent! I never would have seen this one since I'm familiar with the [other pattern](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/132652/6619).